# CSS Grid - Transition for adding/removing cards

Tags: css, animation, transition, css-grid

I created a script to dynamically add and remove cards from a css grid. Just have a look at: https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/ZMRQaE

Adding and removing cards is realized with JS:

```
// Add new card
function addCard(card) {
    card.id = _cards.length + 1;
    _cards.push(card);
    _$main.html('');
    for (let i = 0; i < _cards.length; i++) {
        drawCard(_cards[i]);
    }
}

// Remove card
function removeCard(id) {
    let cardRemoved = false;
    $('#' + _idPrefix + id).remove();
    for (let i = 0; i < _cards.length; i++) {
        if (_cards[i].id === id) {
            _cards.splice(i, 1);
            cardRemoved = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (cardRemoved) {
        // New IDs and redrawing
        _$main.html('');
        for (let i = 0; i < _cards.length; i++) {
            _cards[i].id = i + 1;
            drawCard(_cards[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Draw card
function drawCard(card) {
    let buildStr = '';
    buildStr += '<div class="grid-container ' + card.size + '" id="' + _idPrefix + card.id + '">';
    buildStr += '<div class="grid-item ' + card.color + '">';
    buildStr += '<div class="card-text">' + card.title + '</div></div></div>';
    _$main.html(_$main.html() + buildStr);
}
```

The cards are stored in a global array _cards. After removing a card I need to update their IDs which is similar to their positions (1-8). Please note that frequently there is no limit for adding cards (just 8 are visible).

Because of aesthetic reasons I want to use transitions/animations when cards are removed or added to the grid. By now I did not find a solution.

Adding a new card: The new card should move from right to left until it reaches its position in the grid.
Removing a card: Fading out the card. The grid should "fill" itself, so cards "behind" the removed card should also move from right to left to their new positions.

Comment: what happens if a card switched rows tho?

Comment: Perhaps the card could move beyond the viewport (left) and reappears from the right border of the viewport moving left to its new position.

Comment: well you cant split an element like that, but here's an idea. before removing div, set it invisible first, use transition on transform: translateX to move divs left, after everything is inplace, delete invisible div. for switching rows best i can think of is to clone the div switching rows.

Comment: You can't animate CSS-Grid positions, so you would need to establish the global position of every element in the grid and then adjust **all** of them to the new position values after the element has been removed. It's a lot of calculating!

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I try to solve this with a lib. Just as https://www.npmjs.com/package/animate-css-grid